# Get-ChildItem fails to connect in SQLSERVER drive

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm having some trouble with the SQLSERVER PSDRIVE. See error below.

I only have named instances on my PC, both 2005 and 2008

Added the SQL snapins.

The PC is named YODA
The SQL instance is SQL2008
Navigate to the Databases folder for YODA\SQL2008. You can see the path below.
dir -name spits out a connection error trying to connect to YODASQL2008\DEFAULT when it should be trying to connect to YODA\SQL2008.
Then it outputs the db name which is Twitter in this case.
Is there something missing from my config?

Output:
PS SQLSERVER:\SQL\YODA\SQL2008\Databases> dir -name
Get-ChildItem : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Could not connect to 'YODASQL2008\DEFAULT'. [Failed to connect to
 server YODASQL2008. --> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is
configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
 Server)]

```
At line:1 char:4
+ dir <<<<  -name
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (SQLSERVER:\SQL\...tabases\Twitter:SqlPath) [Get-ChildItem], GenericProviderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConnectFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand Twitter
```

Repeats with error for every database.

Thanks,
Norman

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this on a machine that has a defualt instance as well. You should file a bug on http://connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Connect item 627326 added